# Swig: convert return type std::string to java byte[]

Tags: java, c++, swig

I have a C++ method that returns a std::string. I am using SWIG and I want to add logic to SWIG to make the std::string that is returned, be received in Java as a byte[].

If this is possible, how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

SWIG comes with pre-written interface files for many C++ constructs.  The are found in SWIG's Lib directory for many languages, including Java.

Add `%include <std_string.i>` in your SWIG interface file.  Check SWIG's Lib/Java directory for support for other constructs as well.

Answer (score 0):

std::string has a member function c_str that does essentially that. It would probably make sense to write a wrapper function that calls your function and returns the corresponding c string.