# Swig: convert return type std::string(binary) to java byte[]

Tags: java, swig

My situation is that i have a C++ class (MyClass) with a  method that has the following signature:

```
bool getSerialized(const stdString & name, std::string & serialized);
```

Where name is a in argument and serialized is an out argument.

I got it working by making a %extend and %ignore declarations in the 'i' file as follows:

```
%extend MyClass{
    std::string getSerialized(const std::string & name){
        std::string res;
        $self->getSerialized(name, res);
        return res;
};
%rename("$ignore", fullname=1) "MyClass::getSerialized";
```

So the method con be used from Java like:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
String res = mc.getSerialized("test");
```

But now i have encountered a problem, the serialized std::string contains binary data, including the '\0' character witch indicates the end of a C String, in fact the following code shows the problem in C++:

```
std::string s;
s.push_back('H');
s.push_back('o');
s.push_back(0);
s.push_back('l');
s.push_back('a');
std::cout << "Length of std::string " << s.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "CString: '" << s.c_str() << "'" << std::endl;
```

The code above displays:

```
Length of std::string 5
CString: 'Ho'
```

As i have seen in the wrap file generated by SWIG, the wrap method actually calls c_str(), code of wrap:

```
jstring jresult = 0 ;
std::string result;
result = (arg1)->getSerialized();
jresult = jenv->NewStringUTF((&result)->**c_str()**); 
return jresult;
```

So as expected the received String in Java gets truncated. So how can i change (presumably) my %extend function wrapper so i can return this as a byte array (byte[]), without previously knowing the length of the array. It would be great if the byteArray could be created in the SWIG layer, so i could invoke the method from Java like:

```
byte[] serialized = mc.getSerialized("test");
```

Other considerations:
The use of std::string for storing binary data is given, as is the returned type that uses the Google protobuf library [C++ protobuf usage](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial)

There is a very similar question, including the tittle [Swig: convert return type std::string to java byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937979/swig-convert-return-type-stdstring-to-java-byte?answertab=active#tab-top) but there is no case for binary data, so the solution given there doesn't apply here.

Using SWIG 2.

Comment: Is the length of the output parameter predictable? I.e. can you know the length before the call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you're trying to do with a few typemaps and some JNI. I put together an example:

```
%module test

%include <std_string.i>

%typemap(jtype) bool foo "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) bool foo "byte[]"
%typemap(jni) bool foo "jbyteArray"
%typemap(javaout) bool foo { return $jnicall; }
%typemap(in, numinputs=0) std::string& out (std::string temp) "$1=&temp;"
%typemap(argout) std::string& out {
  $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, $1->size());
  JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, $1->size(), (const jbyte*)$1->c_str());
}
// Optional: return NULL if the function returned false
%typemap(out) bool foo {
  if (!$1) {
    return NULL;
  }
}

%inline %{
struct Bar {
  bool foo(std::string& out) {
    std::string s;
    s.push_back('H');
    s.push_back('o');
    s.push_back(0);
    s.push_back('l');
    s.push_back('a');
    out = s;
    return true;
  }
};
%}
```

It states that the C++ wrapper with return a Java byte array for the functions that match `bool foo`. It also sets up a temporary `std::string` to give to the real implementation of `foo` that hides the input parameter from the Java interface itself.

Once the call has been made it creates and returns a byte array provided the function didn't return false.

I checked that it all worked as expected with:

```
public class run { 
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    String s = "ho\0la";
    System.out.println(s.getBytes().length);

    System.loadLibrary("test");
    Bar b = new Bar();
    byte[] bytes = b.foo();
    s = new String(bytes);
    System.out.println(s + " - " + s.length());
    assert(s.charAt(2) == 0);
  }
}
```

You should be aware of the implications of the cast to `const jbyte*` from the return type of `c_str()` - it may not always be what you wanted.

As an alternative if the size of the output byte array was actually fixed or trivially predictable you could pass that in pre-allocated as the input to begin with. This would work because arrays are effectively passed by reference into functions in the first place.

Comment: Thanks (again :-) ). It worked perfectly. Only one comment, i firstly use the solution without the 'Optional' code, but it didn't compile due to a cast (can't convert from jboolean to jbyteArray, in the wrapper code generated), so it looks like that portion of code isn't optional after all. Appart from that, what implications are in the cast to const jbyte* ?

Comment: @JavierMr - possibly you'd need to write `%typemap(out) bool foo ""` if you didn't want to return `NULL` when the function returned `false`. (Either that or the comment pre-dates the code in the answer I posted)