# Swig: passing unsigned char array from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, arrays, swig

I have a C++ function in a `.cpp` file; say `unsigned char *myFunc()`.
How can I convert that array in a `byte[]` array in Java?
I mean, in Java, I want to do something like:

`byte[] b = myLib.myFunc();`

I am using SWIG and appearently I need to define a kind of conversion from `unsigned char` to `byte` in the `.i` file, but I don't know exactly how.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning a `std::string` instead of `unsigned char*` and `%include <std_string.i>` in your .i file. Thanks to `std_string.i` typemaps, you might end up with a `byte[]` on the receiving side. If you can change the return type of `myFunc` then create a wrapper via `%inline`, something like

```
%inline %{
    std::string myFuncStr() { return myFunc(); }
%}
```

If you want you can `%rename` `myFuncStr` to `myFunc`, thus hiding the fact that the `myFunc` exported to Java is actually a wrapper to the real `myFunc`.

If that doesn't work, Flexo's solution to [Swig: convert return type std::string(binary) to java byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192624/swig-convert-return-type-stdstringbinary-to-java-byte) likely will.

Comment: Thank you Schollii,
I'd like to test your solution. But at the moment I'm having some errors, that I THINK might depend on the fact that my `unsigned char*` contains any ASCII character also greater than 128

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using swig but I do know that if you change your mind and want don't mind using JNI, then the following will work:

On the C++ side:

```
extern "C" jbyteArray JNIEXPORT Java_myPackageName_MyClassName_getByteArray(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    jbyteArray byte_arr = env->NewByteArray(size);

    jbyte bytes[25];  //Some byte array you want to give to java. Could be an unsigned char[25].

    for (int i = 65; i < 90; ++i) //filling it with some A-Z ASCII characters.
    {
        bytes[i - 65] = i;
    }

    env->SetIntArrayRegion(byte_arr, 0, 25, &bytes[0]); //Fill our byte array

    return byte_arr; //return the byte array..
}
```

on the Java side:

```
package myPackageName;

class MyClassName
{
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("myByteArrayModule");
    }

    public static native byte[] getByteArray();
}
```